# Advanced custom fields (Wordpress) inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to display the repeater field inside my Javascript. I have a chart and am trying to mix with repeater fields:

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#mapsvg").mapSvg({
      markerLastID: 20,
      width: 600.4892,
      height: 599.41095,
      colors: {
        baseDefault: "#ffffff",
        selected: 40,
        hover: 20,
        directory: "#ffffff",
        status: {},
        base: "#f2642f",
        stroke: "#1010108a",
        background: "#fff"
      },
      regions: {
        <?php if ( have_rows( 'towns' ) ) : ?>
          <?php while ( have_rows( 'towns' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
          "<?php the_sub_field( 'title_id' ); ?>": {
                id: "<?php the_sub_field( 'title_id' ); ?>",
                id_no_spaces: "<?php the_sub_field( 'title_id' ); ?",
                title: " <?php the_sub_field( 'title' ); ?>",
                disabled: true,
                data: {},
              },
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
          <?php 
        <?php endif; ?>

    });
});
```

Can anybody try to help me with this?

Comment: What isn't working? what's the problem?

Comment: @Diego I have an syntax error, but I don't know how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe show us the generated code or the console error?